# Where can I set GetLegendGraphic width?

Tags: wms

Given a wms-service, the GetCapabilities request returns a legendurl like the following:

```
<LegendURL width="186" height="22">
```

If I specify a width (like below) when using GetLegendGraphic, it is ignored, and the width in LegendUrl  is used.

```
http://myserver/wms/?LAYER=mylayer&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=getlegendgraphic&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=300
```

Where can I change the LegendUrl width? or alternately, how do I use the width setting?

Comment: Please check following url http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set of GetLegendGraphic parameters in the url

For example

```
http://machine_name:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:180
```

For additional details please click [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html)